# Mirror traffic from few interfaces in nexus 3000 switch to 2 interfaces for IPS

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, mirror

I need to be able to mirror traffic from 4 ports on Cisco Nexus 3000 switch to 2 ports on a same switch and connect 2 IPS appliances to those 2 ports. But I don't think it is possible to mirror port to 2 ports on Nexus devices, Any advice in how to solve this?

Comment: It may be overkill for your use case, but I believe this should be possible using Openflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that is not possible to do this directly on the Nexus, since:

- only one destination port is allowed in a monitor configuration
- the same source port cannot be set in two different sessions.
- the destination port of a session cannot be set as the source port of another session.

Some IOS based switches allow this configuration (with 2 destination ports), so if you have such switches with ports available you could do it. Obviously it increases the cost and number of ports required.

Comment: I mark it as correct since you are right about all those limitations. Between using extra Catalyst 3700 switches and hardware network tap we ended up using hardware network tap and It works.  Thanks,